# Opening a XUL window from a bootstrapped extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

Suppose I have a .xul file in the contents folder of my bootstrapped extension that describes a simple window with some labels and edit boxes.

How should I register the window in chrome so that I can open it from inside the `bootstrap.js` whenever I need it?

And how should I open it from Javascript? `window.open("chrome://myextension/content/my_window.xul");`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Firefox 10 restartless add-ons can have [limited `chrome.manifest`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Chrome_Registration#Instructions_supported_in_bootstrapped_add_ons) where you can at least register `content/`, `skin/`, `locale`.

After that it is just a call to `openDialog`, as you already said.